# how to encode to utf text file with unknown encoding jquery

Tags: javascript, file, jquery-mobile, encoding

I have develop an app in HTML5 and JS (phonegap) and now I have to read a text file as an export from an old desktop application written in delphi. This file is an MS SQL export with fixed size strings that i have to import to SQlite of my app.

This text contains Greek Characters and is not encoded in UTF so I read diamonds with questionmarks.

Is there a way to encode this text to UTF programmatically before i read the contents???

It is forbiten to change any delphi code.

This is how I read the text file

```
var billjson = '{"posts" : [', 
i, 
line = 0,
Amountint,
Amountdec;


jQuery.get('Bill.txt',function(data){
alert(data.length);
line=0;

    for (i = 1; i <= ((data.length)/156); i += 1) {
        billjson += '{"Id" :' + '"' + data.substr((line+0), 10).trim() + '"'  + ',';
        billjson += '"Code" :' + '"' + data.substr((line+10), 5).trim() + '"'  +  ',';
        billjson += '"Address" :' + '"' + data.substr((line+14), 40).trim() + '"'  +  ',';
        billjson += '"Name" : ' + '"'  + data.substr((line+54), 50).trim() + '"'  +  ',';
        billjson += '"Description" : ' + '"'  + data.substr((line+104), 8).trim() + '"'  +  ',';
        billjson += '"EntrySeason" : ' + '"'  + data.substr((line+112), 23).trim() + '"'  +  ',';
        billjson += '"Period" : ' + '"'  + data.substr((line+135), 11).trim() + '"'  +  ',';
        Amountint = data.substr((line+146), 7).trim();
        Amountdec = data.substr((line+153), 2).trim();
        billjson += '"Revenue" : ' + '"'  + Amountint + '.' + Amountdec + '"'  +  '}';
        line = i * 156;
        if (line == data.length)
        {
            billjson += ']';
        }
        else 
        {
            billjson += ',';
        }
    }

    if (line == 0)
    {
        billjson += ']';
    }


    billjson += "}";

var mybilljson = jQuery.parseJSON( billjson );
});
```

Please advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to let jquery know what encoding is used in the file it's loading.

```
jQuery.ajaxSetup({
        'beforeSend' : function(xhr) {
             xhr.overrideMimeType('text/plain; charset=iso-8859-7');
        },
});
```